# How to change collation of a table after creating the table?

Tags: mysql, collation

So I have a table that I want to change the collation of it to none, I tried in Operations > Table options but it gives me an error that says "No collation provided" is there any other ways to change it ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I use MySQL.

Comment: I'd start with reading https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/

Comment: I think you have to have one set somewhere

Comment: *change the collation of it to none* This is absolutely impossible. Some charset and collation is compulsory property for a column of any string type. It can be specified explicitly or inherited implicitly. But it presents always.

Comment: You can't change it to "none", the closest to "none" would be to use the "binary" character set, or the "utf8" character set with collation "utf8_bin", which would sort characters strictly by their byte value, or their unicode character number.

Maybe you could give us some background on *why* you want to change it to "none"?

Also "I tried in Operations > Table options" hints towards some GUI tool being used, but you didn't mention what tool that might be ...

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` of a table are simply *defaults* for any columns that get added.

To change either of them, use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ... COLLATION ...;
```

But be very careful about changing the character set -- If Selects are displaying gibberish, using CONVERT TO is likely to make it *impossible* fix.  (Cf: [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) ).

Caution:  `CONVERT TO` changes *all* the string columns.  If you have a column that is deliberately some other charset, it will get changed, too.

If `CONVERT TO` is not a good idea (for above reasons), then do multiple `MODIFY COLUMNs`, one per column that needs changing:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
   MODIFY COLUMN string1 <<column_definition>>
   MODIFY COLUMN string2 <<column_definition>>
   ...;
```

Note: the `column_definition` must include all the other stuff (`NULL`/`NOT NULL`, etc.).  Suggest you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, then copy paste.

Note upon note:  If the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` does not provide the charset/collation on the individual columns, then you should still include such in the MODIFY clause(s).

And...  If you might later add more string columns, ALTER the table as a whole with yet another syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET <<charset_name>>
    DEFAULT COLLATE <<collation_name>>;
```

I agree with Hartmut's Comment on "none".  However, there is something to add:

When specifying a `CHARACTER SET` without also specifying a `COLLATION`, there is a specific default collation for each character set.  To see the defaults:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```

or

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET LIKE 'utf%';
```